# Center QGraphicsView in Widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a QDialog that contains several dock widgets and one QGraphicsView. The widget layout is set to grid, the QGraphicsView size policy is set to fixed on the 2 axes and it the QGraphicsView is center in the empty zone of the QDialog.

I would like to resize my QGraphicsView and let it at the center of the empty zone of the QDialog.
I have tried this code:

```
// resize QGraphicsView
ui->mProjectView->resize(mProject->getSize() + QSize(2,2));
```

But QGraphicsView is adjusting its size to QDialog when resizing QDialog.

I'va tried then this:

```
// resize QGraphicsView
ui->mProjectView->resize(mProject->getSize() + QSize(2,2));
// Adjust size of QDialog to fit new widget's size
ui->centralWidget->adjustSize();
```

But this does not work. QGraphics View keeps last size...

I'm sure the way to achieve it is simple but I'm missing something. Can you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
ui->mProjectView->setFixedSize(mProject->getSize() + QSize(2,2));
```

instead.